# How to publish a nested stack in AWS Serverless Application Repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I've used `sam package` to package my local file to `s3`.

The resulting template looks like this:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Metadata:
  AWS::ServerlessRepo::Application:
    Name: test_nested_stack
    # ... other fields ...

Resources:
  TmpApp:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{{a-bucket-name}}/{{a-file-name}}.template

  # ...
```

When I try to publish using `sam publish`, I got this error:

> Error: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Errors: Resource with id [TmpApp] is invalid. Location property must be an Application Location Object referencing a valid AWS Serverless Application Repository application.
> Please follow the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template-publishing-applications.html

The instruction link doesn't state anything about using an S3 url as nested application location.

And in my use case I can't just publish `TmpApp` to the serverless repository before because it is split into multiple nested template files.